# Dynamic variable in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm

I have the following statement in LINQ:

```
var eventsWithTag = (from occurence in occurrences1
                     join eventTag in serviceContext.CreateQuery("adx_eventtag_event")
                         on occurence.Event.GetAttributeValue<Guid>("adx_eventid") equals eventTag.GetAttributeValue<Guid>("adx_eventid")
                     join tag in serviceContext.CreateQuery("adx_eventtag")
                         on eventTag.GetAttributeValue<Guid>("adx_eventtagid") equals tag.GetAttributeValue<Guid>("adx_eventtagid")
                     where tag.GetAttributeValue<string>("adx_name") == "scotland"
                     select occurence).OrderBy(x => x.Start);
```

This works fine with the fixed string search of "Scotland" in this instance. However I need to replace that to reflect the current page topic. So essentially I need to replace:

```
== "scotland"
```

with:

```
== getBranch()
```

where getBranch returns the relevant branch name as a string.

This would lead me to try:

```
eventsWithTag = (from occurence in occurrences1
join eventTag in serviceContext.CreateQuery("adx_eventtag_event") on occurence.Event.GetAttributeValue<Guid>("adx_eventid") equals eventTag.GetAttributeValue<Guid>("adx_eventid")
join tag in serviceContext.CreateQuery("adx_eventtag") on eventTag.GetAttributeValue<Guid>("adx_eventtagid") equals tag.GetAttributeValue<Guid>("adx_eventtagid")
where tag.GetAttributeValue<string>("adx_name") == getBranch()
select occurence).OrderBy(x => x.Start);
```

But this doesn't work, and from what little I know of LINQ it is because you can't use variables in this way.

So my question is: How can I use the LINQ query above with a dynamic value for the branch.

Please note: I have seen other posts about this but I evidently don't have the LINQ knowledge to transfer them to my specific needs. Just yet!

Comment: Does it give you an error? or does it just return the wrong results?

Comment: No results. However I know the result of getBranch() is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything looks right so I'd double check your getBranch()...

if this works:

```
var branch = "scotland";
eventsWithTag = 
    (from occurence in occurrences1
     join eventTag in serviceContext.CreateQuery("adx_eventtag_event") on occurence.Event.GetAttributeValue<Guid>("adx_eventid") equals eventTag.GetAttributeValue<Guid>("adx_eventid")
     join tag in serviceContext.CreateQuery("adx_eventtag") on eventTag.GetAttributeValue<Guid>("adx_eventtagid") equals tag.GetAttributeValue<Guid>("adx_eventtagid")
     where tag.GetAttributeValue<string>("adx_name") == branch 
     select occurence)
    .OrderBy(x => x.Start);
```

Then p.s.w.g's answer should work, and your issue lies with getBranch returning a value that doesn't match any records...

On a slightly different matter, I'm slightly confused as to why you need to get the actual attributes in your equals statement, because according to [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334415.aspx), it should work fine like this:

```
var branch = "scotland";
eventsWithTag = 
    (from occurence in occurrences1
     join eventTag in serviceContext.CreateQuery("adx_eventtag_event") on occurence.Event["adx_eventid"] equals eventTag["adx_eventid"]
     join tag in serviceContext.CreateQuery("adx_eventtag") on eventTag["adx_eventtagid"] equals tag["adx_eventtagid"]
     where tag["adx_name"] == branch 
     select occurence)
    .OrderBy(x => x.Start);
```

Comment: This linq excluding the orderby bit were written for me by the guys who make the adx Portals for Dynamics eg adxstudio.com

Comment: @PhillHealey I agree with Daryl, if `var branch = "scotland"` works but `var branch = getBranch()` doesn't, the error *has* to be in `getBranch()`.

Comment: Yeah it looks like I wasted hours of my day on a simple capilisation of the first letter scenario! Damn this job! ;-)

Comment: If you started using the early-bound classes that would never happen. :) Btw, I encourage everyone if they aren't using early-bound classes to generate classes with strings for the field names: replacing `CreateQuery("adx_eventtag_event")` with `CreateQuery(adx_eventtag_event.EntityLogicalName)` and `tag["adx_name"]` with `tag[adx_eventtag.fields.adx_name]` - not as good as early bound but better than hard-coding the strings all over the code.

Answer (score 2):

You can just make the call beforehand:

```
var branch = getBranch();
eventsWithTag = 
    (from occurence in occurrences1
     join eventTag in serviceContext.CreateQuery("adx_eventtag_event") on occurence.Event.GetAttributeValue<Guid>("adx_eventid") equals eventTag.GetAttributeValue<Guid>("adx_eventid")
     join tag in serviceContext.CreateQuery("adx_eventtag") on eventTag.GetAttributeValue<Guid>("adx_eventtagid") equals tag.GetAttributeValue<Guid>("adx_eventtagid")
     where tag.GetAttributeValue<string>("adx_name") == branch 
     select occurence)
    .OrderBy(x => x.Start);
```